# Website is not responsive for Iphone 6

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I tried to fix everything within the meta tag and check everything but I could not get the website fully responsive and fix to width for iphone. I tried everything but could not find a solution.

Please help me with a fix for this so that website gets fixed to the width of iphone and no side scroll happens.

Website : http://www.buildwithcraft.co

Comment: Its not clear what you want. You didnt provide any samples. Nor you showed effort.

Comment: okay so the thing is i used meta tag to fix the viewport

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
and even after using this meta tag the website remains larger than the screen for iphone 6

Comment: show some code... and add media queries...

Comment: Here is the link http://www.buildwithcraft.co/projects.html 
This is responsive throughout but when you open the website in iphone 6 it is bit larger than the screen

Comment: What media queries should i add 
Could you please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Some links `www.buildwithcraft.co` and `www.buildwithcraft.co/projects.html` not working properly.

Some other links like `www.buildwithcraft.co/services.html` and `www.buildwithcraft.co/contact.html` working perfectly.

So, compare difference between both pages metadata, is there any changes or not.

**Edit:**

I found that in  `www.buildwithcraft.co/projects.html` you are using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" >
```

but in `www.buildwithcraft.co/services.html` and `www.buildwithcraft.co/contact.html` you are using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

In `www.buildwithcraft.co/` you are not using following code but in all other files you are using this.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

Comment: I cannot figure out , but there is something wrong with the media queries

Comment: post answer, it will help everyone.